# Server hangup on webView android

Tags: android, webview

I am getting message 'Server hangup' when loading url into webView and this message is not implemented in either Android side or server side. If anyone knows how to solve this issue, Please help. Thanks

I have used following code:

```
 private WebView mWebview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mWebview  = new WebView(this);
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));
        mWebview .loadUrl("our server url");
        setContentView(mWebview);
    }

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    Context context;

    public MyWebChromeClient(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        }
    }
```

[Please check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9x2h.jpg)

Comment: There is any ssl error?  You can try to add getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

Google.com is secure domain. You have to use https://www.google.com instead of http://www.google.com.

Comment: It is our server url.

Comment: Ok. Try to open https://www.google.com with same code. If you still get the same error its from client side else the error might be from server side.

Comment: Thanks. I am not getting same error on google.com or any other url's but according to server side they have not implemented 'server hangup' message. so from where it is showing?

Comment: Try to open your server url in browser and check if you are getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this method and set your website url :
   Example :startWebView("https://stackoverflow.com");

```
private void startWebView(String url) {

        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();

        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error:" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        webview.loadUrl(url);

    }
```

Comment: Whenever we test, it is not coming in onReceivedError and this message is very rare. Is there any way to reproduce it continously? so we will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Webview shows you the HTML returned by the URL that has been loaded.
`onReceivedError()` will not be called if you get response containing the error message.

Check what you receive as HTML from server using the following code in `onPageFinished()`.

```
webView.evaluateJavascript(
    "(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();",
    new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                // displays the HTML received after the URL is loaded.
            Log.e("#Eval", "Html -> " + html);
        }
    });
```

As you have mentioned that the message is not implemented in your app, it must have been be received from the server end.